# Can AsciiDocs be used like JavaDoc?

Tags: language-agnostic, asciidoc

I've been using AsciiDocs to write all my documentation, and i was wondering if i could take it a step further and generate the html *from* my source code, like how JavaDoc does with Java source code.

For example, JavaDoc allows the developer to leave in-line comments that will later be used to generate the html documentation. Is this possible with AsciiDocs? Or do I just need to write the documentation separately?

Comment: According to [Asciidoctor manual 36. Comments](https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#comments), you can can add both single and multiline comments in the markup. Single line comments start with a double slash (`//`). Multiline comments are enclosed in a block of four forward slashes (`////`).

Answer (score 2):

Javadoc is somewhat modular and extensible: you can use a custom formatting syntax in javadoc comments if you generate the documentation with a custom "doclet".

For AsciiDoc, such a doclet already exists: https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoclet

---

Javadoc is specific to Java, if you use other programming languages there are other tools. [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) was created specially for C and C++ but it supports several programming languages and comment styles. For Python, there is [pydoc](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/pydoc.html). Whether there's a way to make these support AsciiDoc syntax, you'll have to investigate on your own.

Comment: Yes, but that's only for Java. What about Python, C++? I'm trying to use AsciiDocs to write documentation for all my projects, no matter what the language is. So JavaDoc and AsciiDoclet are limiting me to only Java.

Comment: @Jason Your question does not make that clear. The question and its tags only mention Java and Javadoc. If this question isn't specific to Java then consider editing your question to clarify. Don't just spam language tags however ([tag:language-agnostic] may be appropriate).

Comment: @Jason000 added a note on tools for other PLs